# How to use both onsubmit for validation and onclick for any operation if onsubmit return true in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created form in html now i try to using onsubmit for validation as well as onclick for another operation if onsubmit return true. i cant find the correct way of doing this.

```
<form role="form" onsubmit='return formValidation()'>
        <div class="form-group">
          <p id="bookiderror" style="color: red"></p>
          <label >ಪುಸ್ತಕದ ಐಡಿ:</label>
          <input type="text" id="bookid" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <p id="booknameerror" style="color: red"></p>
          <label>ಪುಸ್ತಕದ ಹೆಸರು:</label>
          <input type="text" id="bookname" class="form-control">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <p id="rupeeserror" style="color: red"></p>
          <label >ರೂಪಾಯಿ:</label>
          <input type="text"id="rupees" class="form-control">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <p id="bookpubishererror" style="color: red"></p>
          <label >ಪುಸ್ತಕದ ಪ್ರಕಾಶಕರು:</label>
          <input type="text" id="bookpublisher" class="form-control">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <p id="bookeditionerror" style="color: red"></p>
          <label >ಪುಸ್ತಕದ ಆವೃತ್ತಿ:</label>
          <input type="text" id="bookedition" class="form-control">
        </div>
         <div class="form-group">
          <p id="bookyearerror" style="color: red"></p>
          <label >ಪುಸ್ತಕದ ವರ್ಷ:</label>
          <input type="text" id="bookyear" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="AddBook" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addbook()" id="submit"/>
      </form>
```

Comment: Please include the code for ```formValidation()``` and ```addbook()```.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so like this. The **formValidation** method should return false otherwise page will refresh.

```
function formValidation(){
     //write your formValidation logic here
     if(form.isValid){
         //call your add book here
         addbook();
     }
     return false;
}
```

Comment: This won't matter, if that file is loaded as well with this file in your I index.html file

Answer (score 0):

```
function formValidation(){


//Enter your validation logic here.
if (false) return false;

return true; //default
```

}

```
function addBook() {

if (formValidation()){
    //Your insertion code here.
}
else
{

    alert('Error message.'); 

}
```

}

Now, just remove the onClick function then put the addBook() function to your onSubmit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The click event fires first. Only after it is resolved with the default behaviour of the submit button activate and trigger the submission.

Consequently it isn't possible to run the submit handler before the click handler.

You need to either:

- Do all the tests your submit handler does at the top of each click handler.
- Let the click handler just record which submit button was activated, and then use that to determine what to do at the end of the submit handler.